# Slidable Segment Control containing only 1 tableview on each page

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm currently working on an online shop application which can view any product being sell and purchase it directly from the app.

How does one implement a slidable segment control with unpredictable number of section which connects to only one view controller containing table view that update itself based on the section selected? ( So there's like a slide effect when one select another section as the tableview is being updated )

There are a lot of category which have different number of additional sub - category which act as the section of the segment control. I don't really want to flood my storyboard with a lot of View controller with the same tableview containing the same cell. So , let's say there is this one main category containing 50+ sub - category , i don't think i should make 50 View controllers with the same tableview. Thanks before. :)

Comment: Oh , my bad. It's Swift 2.2.

Comment: Have you checked GitHub for such control? There are many. Search on google with text  "**segmented view controller github**"

Comment: I did, but most of them use multiple view controllers or none at all or even using objective-c which i don't really understand. I'm currently using **MXSegmentedPager** , but i couldn't do the swipe left or right effect on a single multipliable uiviewcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to Re-use one View Controller, I have Override some methods and added following methods and did not change anything else in the code:

- `numberOfPagesInSegmentedPager`
- `didSelectViewWithIndex`
- `segueIdentifierForPageAtIndex`

Hence, you can use only one View Controller.

I have made changes in the original source code of MXSegmentedPager's **Example-Swift** project:

**MXViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit
import MXSegmentedPager

class MXViewController: MXSegmentedPagerController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.segmentedPager.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        // Parallax Header       
        self.segmentedPager.parallaxHeader.view = MXHeaderView.instanceFromNib();
        self.segmentedPager.parallaxHeader.mode = MXParallaxHeaderMode.Fill;
        self.segmentedPager.parallaxHeader.height = 150;
        self.segmentedPager.parallaxHeader.minimumHeight = 20;


        // Segmented Control customization
        self.segmentedPager.segmentedControl.selectionIndicatorLocation = HMSegmentedControlSelectionIndicatorLocationDown;
        self.segmentedPager.segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.segmentedPager.segmentedControl.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()];
        self.segmentedPager.segmentedControl.selectedTitleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.orangeColor()]
        self.segmentedPager.segmentedControl.selectionStyle = HMSegmentedControlSelectionStyleFullWidthStripe
        self.segmentedPager.segmentedControl.selectionIndicatorColor = UIColor.orangeColor()


        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.segmentedPager.reloadData()
            //self.segmentedPager.pager.showPageAtIndex(1, animated: false)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //set here the total number of categories
    override func numberOfPagesInSegmentedPager(segmentedPager: MXSegmentedPager) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    //Here you can get to know , which view user has selected.
    override func segmentedPager(segmentedPager: MXSegmentedPager, didSelectViewWithIndex index: Int) {
        print("didSelectViewWithIndex:\(index)")
    }

    override func segmentedPager(segmentedPager: MXSegmentedPager, segueIdentifierForPageAtIndex index: Int) -> String {
        return "mx_page_0"
    }

    override func segmentedPager(segmentedPager: MXSegmentedPager, titleForSectionAtIndex index: Int) -> String {
        return ["Table", "Web", "Text"][index];
    }

    override func segmentedPager(segmentedPager: MXSegmentedPager, didScrollWithParallaxHeader parallaxHeader: MXParallaxHeader) {
        NSLog("progress %f", parallaxHeader.progress)
    }
}
```

**Storyboard:**

Delete all the segues except one with identifier "`mx_page_0`":

[image: Storyboard]

**Data loading according to View Controller:**

Take a common array, and update it whenever user Slides.

Comment: God , it worked. Thanks , buddy! But how does one , let's say , there's an array of `["0","1","2"]` and `["3","4"]` acting as the number of cell for the table view, split them into their respective section with their tableview?

Comment: You mean how to load/change data into cell, when user slides the View Controller?

Comment: Yes it is , as i return the data in array for all the sub categories currently being viewed from database, while still keeping the original prototype cell design.

Comment: Take a common array, and update it whenever user Slides. And then reload the table.

Comment: Ah , my bad. It's not when the user slide between section, it's when the user load the first view controller with the pager so it's like there is a data request query to save it into an array before returning `mx_page_0`

Comment: You want to load the array data in to the table right?

Comment: Yes, but i only want to load it only once when the user viewed the view controller on the left for all the sub - categories. How should i implement the query and data passing looping for each section with their respective table view? Sorry, i'm pretty new to swift and xcode.

Comment: Kindly post a new question with your API code which fetches the data and table view methods.